# Like str.join but with a random seperator

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I join an iterable with a random (or otherwise chosen) string?

```py
from itertools import cycle

options = cycle((
    ' and ',
    ' also ',
    ', ',
    ' not to mention '
))

things = ["thing A", "thing B", "thing C", "thing D also", "some other things"]

print(next(options).join(things))
```

Output: `thing A and thing B and thing C and thing D also and some other things`
Desired output: `thing A and thing B also thing C, thing D not to mention some other things`

What I've tried:

```
from itertools import cycle

options = cycle((
    ' and ',
    ' also ',
    ', ',
    ' not to mention '
))

things = ["thing A", "thing B", "thing C", "thing D also", "some other things"]

result = ''
for i, s in enumerate(things, 1):
    result += s
    if i % len(s):
        result += next(options)

print(result)
```

Output: `thing A and thing B also thing C, thing D also not to mention some other things and`
Desired output: `thing A and thing B also thing C, thing D also not to mention some other things`
This does more stuff I don't want depending on the length of `things` as well

Comment: do you want it to be *random* or to have this cycling behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `functools.reduce()` together with `random.choice()`:

```py
import functools
import random


options = (" and ", " also ", ", ", " not to mention ")


def random_join(a, b):
    return random.choice(options).join((a, b))


functools.reduce(random_join, things)
```

Output:

```py
'thing A, thing B and thing C not to mention thing D also and some other things'
```

Note however that you have `thing D also` in `things` which I'm not sure was intentional, and sometimes produces awkward results:

```py
'thing A and thing B, thing C, thing D also also some other things'
```

### Non-quadratic algorithm

The solution above is, as pointed out, quadratic in time. If, for some reason, you're actually solving this problem at a large scale then you probably want to think about another approach if performance really matters. This would *probably* suffice however:

```py
def random_join(*words):
    result = [words[0]]
    for word in words[1:]:
        result.extend([random.choice(options), word])
    return "".join(result)
```

Note that this is still a somewhat sloppy implementation, as it involves occasionally needing to reallocate new memory in order to grow the list of characters, which can be a costly operation.

Comment: It should be noted that this algorithm is quadratic time and will not scale great

Comment: Yep. I found it hard at the time to imagine how OP might run into any issues though :D

Comment: @ddejohn: I'll note, the "non-quadratic" algorithm given is only (semi-)non-quadratic on CPython as an implementation detail (one PEP8 specifically says not to rely on); on any other Python interpreter, it'll still be quadratic because Python's `str` is immutable, so each concatenation recopies everything. To fix, you'd need to accumulate the `str` components in a `list` and `''.join(thelist)` back together at the end, or write them to an `io.StringIO` which you get the value of at the end.